# Approximation of reciprocal of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Is $\frac{1}{1 + z}\approx 1-z$ if $z$ is small? Is there any proof of this?

Comment: Recall that $$\forall z\in \mathbb C\left[|z|<1\implies \dfrac 1{1-(-z)}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left((-z)^n\right)\right].$$ Try to use this with whatever $\approx$ means.

Comment: So you are saying that,$\frac{1}{1-z} \approx 1-z$, when $n=1$. So the closer $z$ is to 0 the better this approximation becomes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $|z|<1$ then
$$
\frac{1}{1+z}=1-z+z^2-z^3+z^4-z^5+\cdots
$$
For $z$ small, all the higher-order powers are much smaller than $z$ and so
$$
\frac{1}{1+z}\approx 1-z
$$

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{z \to 0} |\frac{1}{1 + z} - (1 - z)| = \lim_{z \to 0} |\frac{1 - (1- z)(1 + z)}{1 + z} |= \lim_{z \to 0}|\frac{1 - 1 - z^2 } {1 + z}| = \lim_{z \to 0} |\frac{-z^2 } {1 + z} |  = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{|-z^2| } {|1 + z|} = 0$

So, in that sense, yes.

Comment: Works for $\frac{1}{1 + z}\approx 1+z$ too.

Comment: However, the other one is actually the first two terms in the infinite sum you provided in your comments and is a true approximation of $\frac{1}{1+z}$, the other one is actually only equal at $z=0$.

Comment: They are both only equal at $z = 0$ - they are both approximations. There may be some interest which is the closer approximation.